# Display a mandatory name and email box in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, r-googlesheets

I have been building a Shiny app that displays some information gathered from the web.

Im using shinydashboard to create the app.

I would like to have a startup box that is either a login page or a Name and Email input box that anyone that wants to use the app needs to fill before seeing the data.

Also I would like to gather that data and add a row to a googlesheet anytime someone uses the app, and to top it up, record the searches they make using the app.

I have tried all the tutorials available, and does not seem to work.

Here is UI:

```
 library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(RISmed)
library(ggplot2)
library(DT)
library(shinydashboard)

shinyUI(dashboardPage(skin = "blue",
                      dashboardHeader(
                      dashboardSidebar(dashboardSidebar(
                              sidebarMenu(
                                      menuItem("Homepage", tabName = "home", icon = icon("flask")),
                                      menuItem("Search Product", tabName = "product", icon = icon("info")),
                                      menuItem("Search Catalog", tabName = "catalog", icon = icon("map-pin")),
                                      menuItem("Support", tabName = "support", icon = icon("support"))))),
                   dashboardBody(

                           tabItems(
                                tabItem("home",
                                        fluidPage(##DETAILS

                   tabItem("product",
                            fluidPage(
                                    sidebarLayout(
                                            sidebarPanel(

                                                    textInput("name", "Protein name", value = "actin"),
                                                    selectInput("clonality", "Clonality", choices = c("Monoclonal", "Polyclonal")),

                                                    submitButton("Search")),
                                            mainPanel(
                                                      tabsetPanel(
                                                              tabPanel("Products", DT::dataTableOutput("table1")),
                                                              tabPanel("More Info", dataTableOutput("table2")),
                                                              tabPanel("Titles", tableOutput("table3")),
                                                              tabPanel("Authors", tableOutput("table4")),
                                                              tabPanel("Searches", plotOutput("plot")))
                                            )))),

                   tabItem("catalog",
                            fluidPage(
                                    sidebarLayout(
                                            sidebarPanel(
                                                    helpText("Search by Catalog Number"),
                                                    textInput("model", "Model Number"),
                                                    submitButton("Search")),
                                            mainPanel(
                                                    tabsetPanel(
                                                            tabPanel("Product", dataTableOutput("table5")),
                                                            tabPanel("More Info", dataTableOutput("table6"))

                                                    ))))),
                        tabItem("support",
                                   fluidRow(
                                           mainPanel(
                                                             tabsetPanel(
                                                                     tabPanel("Contacts", ##DETAILS                                                           
                                                                     tabPanel("Documents", ##DETAILS

                                                                              ))))

                   ))))
```

Now for the server:

```
library(shiny)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(RISmed)
library(ggplot2)
library(DT)
```

##DATA LOADING

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

        output$table1 <- DT::renderDataTable({


                search <- input$name
                df <- subset(products, grepl(search, products$Name, ignore.case = TRUE)==TRUE)
                df$Model <- paste0("<a href=",df$URL1,"target='_blank>",df$Model,"</a>")
                df2 <- subset(df, Clonality == input$clonality)
                df3  <- df2[,tbl]

                datatable(df3, escape = FALSE)%>%formatStyle("Reviews",backgroundColor=styleInterval(1.10, c("red", "green")))%>%formatStyle("Name","Price Dollars",backgroundColor=styleEqual("132 214.5 264", "orange"))


        })

        output$table2 <- DT::renderDataTable({
                search <- input$name
                df <- subset(products, grepl(search, products$Name, ignore.case = TRUE)==TRUE)
                df$Pathways <- paste0("<a href='",df$Pathway.URL.1,"' target='_blank'>",df$Pathways.1,"</a>", "</br>","<a href='",df$Pathway.URL.2,"' target='_blank'>",df$Pathways.2,"</a>")
                df2 <- subset(df, Clonality == input$clonality)
                df3  <- df2[,tbl2]

                return(df3)      
        }, escape = FALSE)


        table3 <- reactive({

                search_topic <- input$name
                search_query <- EUtilsSummary(search_topic, mindate = 2017, maxdate=2018, retmax = 100)

                records <- EUtilsGet(search_query)
                Titles <- as.data.frame(((ArticleTitle(records))))
                colnames(Titles) = "Articles Titles"
                withProgress(session, min=1, max=15, {
                        setProgress(message = 'Calculation in progress',
                                    detail = 'This may take a while...')
                        for (i in 1:15) {
                                setProgress(value = i)
                                Sys.sleep(0.1)
                        }
                })
                print(Titles)
        })


        table4 <- reactive({

                search_topic <- input$name
                search_query <- EUtilsSummary(search_topic, mindate = 2017, maxdate=2018, retmax = 100)

                records <- EUtilsGet(search_query)

                AuthorList<-Author(records)
                LastFirst<-sapply(AuthorList, function(x)paste(x$LastName,x$ForeName))
                auths<-as.data.frame(sort(table(unlist(LastFirst)), dec=TRUE))
                colnames(auths)<- c("Author", "Count")
                auths <- cbind(Author = rownames(auths), auths)
                rownames(auths) <- NULL
                withProgress(session, min=1, max=15, {
                        setProgress(message = 'Calculation in progress',
                                    detail = 'This may take a while...')
                        for (i in 1:15) {
                                setProgress(value = i)
                                Sys.sleep(0.1)
                        }
                })
                print(auths)

        })


        plot1 <- reactive({

                search_topic <- input$name
                search_query <- EUtilsSummary(search_topic, mindate = 2017, maxdate=2018, retmax = 1000)

                records <- EUtilsGet(search_query)

                y <- data.frame(cbind("year"= YearPubmed(records), "month"= MonthPubmed(records)))
                date()
                count<-table(y)
                y$date <- as.Date(strptime(paste(y$year, y$month, "01", sep="-"), "%Y-%m-%d", tz = "UTC"), origin="1970-01-01")
                withProgress(session, min=1, max=15, {
                        setProgress(message = 'Calculation in progress',
                                    detail = 'This may take a while...')
                        for (i in 1:15) {
                                setProgress(value = i)
                                Sys.sleep(0.1)
                        }
                })
                y %>% group_by(date) %>% summarise(n.citation = length(date)) %>%
                        ggplot(aes(x=date, y = n.citation)) + geom_point(color="black", shape=20, alpha = 0.6) + 
                        geom_line(color="black") +
                        ggtitle(input$name) + xlab("Date") + ylab("Number of Citations") + theme_bw() + 
                        theme(panel.border = element_blank(), 
                              panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
                              panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
                              axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) 

        })

        output$table5 <- DT::renderDataTable({

                search <- input$model
                df <- subset(products, products$Model==input$model)
                df$Model <- paste0("<a href='",df$URL1,"' target='_blank'>",df$Model,"</a>")
                df2  <- df[,tbl]
                colnames(df2) <- c("Name", "Model", "Short Description", "Human Gene Symbol", "Sizes", "Price Pounds", "Price Dollars", "Price Euros", "Reviews" )
                return(df2)        


        }, escape = FALSE)

        output$table6 <- DT::renderDataTable({
                search <- input$model
                df <- subset(products, products$Model==input$model)
                df$Pathways <- paste0("<a href='",df$Pathway.URL.1,"' target='_blank'>",df$Pathways.1,"</a>", "</br>","<a href='",df$Pathway.URL.2,"' target='_blank'>",df$Pathways.2,"</a>"
                                      ,"</a>", "</br>","<a href='",df$Pathway.URL.3,"' target='_blank'>",df$Pathways.2,"</a>"
                                      ,"</a>", "</br>","<a href='",df$Pathway.URL.4,"' target='_blank'>",df$Pathways.4,"</a>"
                                      ,"</a>", "</br>","<a href='",df$Pathway.URL.5,"' target='_blank'>",df$Pathways.5,"</a>"
                                      ,"</a>", "</br>","<a href='",df$Pathway.URL.6,"' target='_blank'>",df$Pathways.6,"</a>"
                                      ,"</a>", "</br>","<a href='",df$Pathway.URL.7,"' target='_blank'>",df$Pathways.7,"</a>"
                                      ,"</a>", "</br>","<a href='",df$Pathway.URL.8,"' target='_blank'>",df$Pathways.8,"</a>"
                                      ,"</a>", "</br>","<a href='",df$Pathway.URL.9,"' target='_blank'>",df$Pathways.9,"</a>"
                                      ,"</a>", "</br>","<a href='",df$Pathway.URL.10,"' target='_blank'>",df$Pathways.10,"</a>"
                                      ,"</a>", "</br>","<a href='",df$Pathway.URL.11,"' target='_blank'>",df$Pathways.11,"</a>"
                                      ,"</a>", "</br>","<a href='",df$Pathway.URL.12,"' target='_blank'>",df$Pathways.12,"</a>"
                                      ,"</a>", "</br>","<a href='",df$Pathway.URL.13,"' target='_blank'>",df$Pathways.13,"</a>"
                                      ,"</a>", "</br>","<a href='",df$Pathway.URL.14,"' target='_blank'>",df$Pathways.14,"</a>"
                                      ,"</a>", "</br>","<a href='",df$Pathway.URL.15,"' target='_blank'>",df$Pathways.15,"</a>"
                                      ,"</a>", "</br>","<a href='",df$Pathway.URL.16,"' target='_blank'>",df$Pathways.16,"</a>"
                                      ,"</a>", "</br>","<a href='",df$Pathway.URL.17,"' target='_blank'>",df$Pathways.17,"</a>")
                df2 <- df[,tbl2]

                return(df2)      
        }, escape = FALSE)

        getPage<-function() {
                search <- input$model
                df <- subset(products, products$Model==input$model)
                df$URL2 <- paste0("https://",df$URL1)
                return(tags$iframe(src = df$URL2
                                   , style="width:100%;",  frameborder="0"
                                   ,id="iframe"
                                   , height = "1000px", seamless = TRUE))
        }



        output$table3 <- renderTable(table3())
        output$table4 <- renderTable(table4())
        output$plot <- renderPlot(plot1(), width = 850, height = 425)

})
```

Sorry about the messy. This is a work in progress.

Im having now a new issue that is the Hyperlink in the df$Model come with my local 127.0.0.1 before the link, making it unusable.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please share a working example to ensure that people answer your question.

Comment: Data cannot be shared. The dataset is almost 150Mb csv.
I just would like a instruction on what tool to use to create a form that stands before all the data display and connect to googlesheets. Thank you so much

Comment: Your `ui` code shows error and try to create a sample dataset and share it.

Comment: The dataset is a 92 column dataset. Is incredible hard to recreate even for a sample.